# Python read windows Command Line output

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I am trying to execute a command in python and read its output on command line in windows.

I have written the following code so far:

```
def build():
    command = "cobuild archive"
    print "Executing build"
    pipe = Popen(command,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
    while True:     
        line = pipe.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            print line
```

I want to execute the command cobuild archive in command line and read it's output. However, the above code is giving me this error.

```
 File "E:\scripts\utils\build.py", line 33, in build
   pipe = Popen(command,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You need to indent your code

Comment: What happens when you enter that command in the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked. I needed to pass shell=True for the arguments

```
def build():    
command = "cobuild archive" 
pipe = Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)    

while True:         
    line = pipe.stdout.readline()
    if line:            
        print line
    if not line:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

This error says that the `subprocess` module is unable to locate your `executable(.exe)`

here `"cobuild archive"`

Suppose, if your executable in this path: `"C:\Users\..\Desktop"`,
then, do,

```
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\..\Desktop")
```

and then use your `subprocess`

Comment: Using output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd) is giving me 

(1, "'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.")

Comment: Also the batch file cobuild archive isn't triggered.

Comment: is your `cobuild archive` is an executable ?, to check this try running same from the `command prompt` (in the same directory), if its still throwing error, the problem is with your executable !!!

Comment: Yes. If I just run cobuild archive from the command prompt, it runs fine. I have been using that command from command line for a long time now. The executable isn't the problem. Its my python code.

Comment: Then in your `subprocess` call try, `cmd = ["cobuild", "archive"]`, and pass this `cmd` to your subprocess

Comment: pipe = Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) works fine. I had to add shell=True

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind to post your code with the correct indentations please? They have a large effect in python - another way of doing this is:

```
import commands
# the command to execute
cmd = "cobuild archive"
# execute and get stdout
output = commands.getstatusoutput( cmd )
# do something with output
# ...
```

**Update:**

The commands module has been removed in Python 3, so this is a solution for python 2 only.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Comment: The problem is not with the console read, but the execution itself

Comment: Please post comments like "Do you mind to post your code with the correct indentations please?" as a comment, or just edit the original post - thanks!